# RavenDB concurrent put

Tags: c#, ravendb

I started using RavenDB and I am getting concurrency exceptions when I am creating an entity and linking the entity to another entity, for examples:

- Class - List students - string is the student id
- Student

When creating a new student I am fetching the related class and adding the student to the "students" list. I saw that this storing and adding this relation is my bottleneck in my application. 
 
How I can fix this concurrency problem? or maybe I can do this linking in other way? or update the Class with PatchRequest and then I won't have problems with concurrency?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options

1. Retry on concurrency failure
2. Reduce contention on the Class entity.

Really, you have a many-to-many relationship between students and classes - so you can store the related key on either side of the relationship (or both sides if desired).

If your app works more frequently with classes than students, try putting a list of ClassIds on each student.  You can still get back a list of all students in the class via a query.

Aside - I suggest "Course" instead of "Class" to avoid stepping on keywords in c#

Comment: My example wasn't good enough , actually I have one to many relationship, those updating the "Course" with PatchRequest won't fix this problem?

Comment: It will side-step the problem, and you won't notice it.  You probably don't want to use it though, because you will not have any transcational guarantees.  You say you are one-to-many, that means that a student can never take more than one course.  Are you sure about that?  There is more to consider. Are courses offered once and then never again?  If not, then perhaps you need a separate "Enrollment" or "Registration" document to track which students are in which courses at what times.

Comment: Student and Course is just an example.. I don't have Student/Course objects